# how can I download a google compute engine image

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can I download a google compute engine image that was created from a snapshot of a persistent disk? There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do this through the console.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to download a image or snapshot from GCE, but there's a way to save an image and store it in Google Cloud Storage(GCS) where it can be downloaded. You can use the standard [`gcimagebundle`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages) tool to do this.

You can also create this image using the [`dd` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)). On a temporary disk that’s bigger than the one you want to image, run this:

```
dd if=/dev/disk/by-id/google-diskname of=disk.img bs=5M
```

You can then run this command to copy it over to GCS:

```
gsutil cp disk.img gs://bucket/image.img
```

And later, you can:

```
gsutil cat gs://bucket/image.img | dd of=/dev/disk/by-id/google-newdisk bs=5M
```

This will allow you to make an image of your disk and then send it to GCS where you can download it using either the web interface or gsutil.

Comment: I had earlier dismissed using the gcimagebundle tool and just realized (thanks to your reply) that it can be used on a *running* instance. In fact, it says so right in the [README.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/gcimagebundle) and I never saw it. So thanks again!

Comment: #1. Is there a way to do this with the boot (attached) disk ?

#2. @sparker: That link is dead, but I found the README.md but it doesnt say anything about a running instance..where did you get that from?

And according to GCS docs, " You can't create an image from a disk that's attached to a VM instance."

Comment: This shouldn't be so complicated.... I hate how contrived the cloud seems to be. I much prefer a local hyper-visor, but now that I pay for internet/GB it makes sense to use the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the current answer, you can it directly download a file using SSH / SCP, by adding your public key to the "SSH Keys". Then, using your own terminal :

```
sheryl:~ sangprabo$ scp prabowo.murti@123.456.789.012:/var/www/my-file.tar.gz . 
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/sangprabo/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I prefer that way so I don't need to create a bucket first. CMIIW.