# Unable to increase disk size on file system

Tags: linux, ssh, google-compute-engine, disk

I'm currently trying to log in to one of the instances created on google cloud, but found myself unable to do so. Somehow the machine escaped my attention and the hard disk got completely full. Of course I wanted to free some disk space and make sure the server running could restart, but I am facing some issues.

First off, I have found the guide on increasing the size of the persistent disk (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk). I followed that and already set it 50 GB which should be fine for now.

However, on file system level because my disk is full I cannot make any SSH connection. The error is simply a timeout caused by the fact that there is absolutely no space for the SSH deamon to write to its log. Without any form of connection I cannot free some disk space and/or run the "resize2fs" command.

Furthermore, I already tried different approaches.

1. I seem to not be able to change the boot disk to something else.
2. I created a snapshot and tried to increase the disk size on the new
   instance I created from that snapshot, but it has the same problem
   (filesystem is stuck at 15GB).
3. I am not allowed to mount the disk as an additional disk in another
   instance.

Currently I'm pretty much out of ideas. The important data on the disk was back-upped but I'd rather have the settings working as well. Does anyone have any clues as where to start?

[EDIT]
Currently still trying out new things. I have also tried to run shutdown- and startup scripts that remove /opt/* in order to free some temporary space but the script either don't run or provide some error I cannot catch. It's pretty frustrating working nearly blind I must say.

The next step for me would be to try and get the snapshot locally. It should be doable using the bucket but I will let you know.

[EDIT2]
Getting a snapshot locally is not an option either or so it seems. Images from the google cloud instances can only be created or deleted, but not downloaded.

I'm now out of ideas.

Comment: Can you enter to the system in any way?
If you can't change your boot, put the disk in other system, nor get into system in any way. it's very complicated.

Comment: can you enter by FTP? maybe you can delete some file just for a login

Comment: No I don't seem to be able to enter the system in any way at all. It's a cloud based server so I'm only allowed to enter on OS level, but due to the disk being full log files can't be written and therefor no SSH-attempt is allowed. Furthermore, I have no other services (FTP/SMB) running on said machine.

Comment: Can you ask for restore a sane backup?

Comment: I'm afraid not. We have the bronze support configuration so basically we're entitled to stack overflow questions only. Everything else we need to do ourselves. Meanwhile I have been trying some other options as well. I will update the question with that.

Comment: Can you download and upload a disk image?

Comment: Yes that is the method that I'm currently trying. I had to delete the instance because "hot-swapping" on disk-detach still has a bug. Currently creating the image of off the disk. Maybe I can download it using bucket tool and mount it as a secondary disk locally.

Comment: Never mind that. I am able to create an image from the disk but unable to actually download it. I came across another stack overflow question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769364/how-can-i-download-a-google-compute-engine-image) but this person assumes access to the VM in order to use DD and create an actual image-file which he then copies to a bucket.

Comment: if you can download a image, you can mount it with a live cd or live usb, and delete some files, then you can upload this fixed disk image. 
If there is a bug in download or upload this disk image, yo can ask it to support.

Comment: Thnx for your comments and assistance, but I believe I found an answer and possible solution. Google does not allow you to download an image. Instead I found that there is a bug in the front-end for mounting disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer. These steps were taken:

- In the GUI I increased the size of the disk to 50 GB.
- In the GUI I detached the drive by deleting the machine whilst
  ensuring that I did not throw away the original disk.
- In the GUI I created a new machine with a sufficiently big harddisk.
- On the command line (important!!) I attached the disk to the newly
  created machine (the GUI option has a bug still ...)

After that I could mount the disk as a secondary disk and perform all the operations I needed.

Keep in mind: By default google cloud solutions do NOT use logical volume management, so pvresize/lvresize/etc. is not installed and resize2fs might not work out of the box.